# How to add a heading to a comment box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function to save in a comment box, the time&date and the username of who made a change in the cell, keeping in memory the last five changes.

When a sixth change is made, it deletes the oldest one, and saves the newest. I am also formatting the comment box with the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim CommentBox As Object
    Dim CommentString As String
    Dim CommentTemp As String
    Dim LastDoubleDotPosition As Integer
    Dim LongestName As Integer
    Dim FinalComment As String

    If Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = "" Then GoTo EndeSub
    If Target.Row <= 2 Then GoTo EndeSub
    If Not Intersect(Range("C:JA"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo EndeSub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B" & Target.Row) = Now
    End If

    Application.Volatile

    Set CommentBox = Range("B" & Target.Row).Comment

    If Not CommentBox Is Nothing Then
        If CommentBox.Text <> "" Then
            CommentString = CommentBox.Text
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Comment.Delete
        End If
    Else
        CommentString = ""
    End If

    CommentTemp = CommentString
    LastDoubleDotPosition = 0
    LongestName = 0

    If InStr(CommentTemp, ":") > 0 Then StillTwoDoubleDots = True

    Do While InStr(CommentTemp, ":") > 0

        If InStr(CommentTemp, ":") > LongestName Then LongestName = InStr(CommentTemp, ":")
        CommentTemp = Right(CommentTemp, Len(CommentTemp) - InStr(CommentTemp, ":"))

    Loop

    count = CountChr(CommentString, ":")

    If count >= 6 Then

        LastDoubleDotPosition = Len(CommentString) - Len(CommentTemp) - 1
        CommentString = Left(CommentString, LastDoubleDotPosition - 13)

    End If

    'insert comment
    FinalComment = Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm") & " " & "by" & " " & Application.UserName & vbCrLf & CommentString 'newComment and the oldcomment
    FinalComment = Replace(FinalComment, CustomComment, vbNullString)
    FinalComment = CustomComment & FinalComment
    Range("B" & Target.Row).AddComment FinalComment

    Set CommentBox = Range("B" & Target.Row).Comment

    LongestName = LongestName * 5
    If LongestName < 150 Then LongestName = 150

    With CommentBox
        .Shape.Height = 70
        .Shape.Width = LongestName
    End With

EndeSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Public Function CountChr(Expression As String, Character As String) As Long

    Dim Result As Long
    Dim Parts() As String
    Parts = Split(Expression, Character)
    Result = UBound(Parts, 1)
    If (Result = -1) Then
    Result = 0
    End If
    CountChr = Result

End Function
```

Is it possible also to add a headline for that comment box?

For example I have the following output:

```
13.11.2017 17:39 by user2

13.11.2017 17:35 by user1

13.11.2017 17:35 by user3

13.11.2017 17:34 by user1

13.11.2017 17:33 by user1
```

I want to add a bold heading, let's say: "Updated on:", and the output will be:

```
Updated on:

    13.11.2017 17:39 by user2

    13.11.2017 17:35 by user1

    13.11.2017 17:35 by user3

    13.11.2017 17:34 by user1

    13.11.2017 17:33 by user1
```

Comment: You can try copying the content of your comment and add the comment with your header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a public constant like this:

```
Public Const UPDATED_ON = "UPDATED ON" & vbCrLf
```

When you are writing to the comment at the end, try to replace the value of UPDATED_ON with nothing like this:

```
FinalComment = Replace(FinalComment, UPDATED_ON, vbNullString)
```

At the end add the UPDATED_ON on the top like this:

```
FinalComment = UPDATED_ON & FinalComment
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. i was thinking to do it in a more complicated way. If I will succeed I will post the solution.